# Chaining Requests in Angular 1.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angular 1.3 so I can't use promises.   I have multiple $http requests that I need to chain, pulling 500 records at a time from the database.  I'm not sure how to do it without promises.

```
$mfServ.retrieveOutagePlanning($scope.serialNo, dtStart, dtEnd, reportName).success(function (data, status) {
                $scope.outageTotalData = data; <-- cannot read property of undefined
}
```

=====================

```
outagePlanningRequest:function(req) {
    return $http(req).success(function(data, status) { 
        console.log(req, data)});
},

retrieveOutagePlanning: function(turbineNum, startDate, endDate, reportName) {

        var tmpDateStart = new Date(startDate);
        var startMilliseconds = tmpDateStart.getTime();
        var tmpDateEnd = new Date(endDate);
        var endMilliseconds = tmpDateEnd.getTime();


        var returnData = [];
        var currentPage = 0;

        var req = {
            url: "/dppws/getSelectedCharts/297957/DW/" + startMilliseconds + "/" + endMilliseconds + "?page=0&size=500",
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };


            this.outagePlanningRequest(req).success(function (data, status) {
                if (data.length == 0) {
                    return returnData;  <-- how do I trigger a 'success' here?
                } else {
                    returnData.push(data);
                    currentPage++;
                    req.url = "/dppws/getSelectedCharts/297957/" + chartString + "/" + startMilliseconds + "/" + endMilliseconds + "?page=" + currentPage + "&size=500"
                }
            })



    },
```

====================

Also, how would I keep repeating the loop?  In Angular 1.6 I would chain promises or use observables.   How could I do that in Angular 1.3?

Comment: Please upgrade, you have major security vulnerabilities that were since patched. Also, you will have a hard time finding answers to your questions.

Comment: Honestly though, just wrap your `$http` service with something more modern yourself. You may find `.decorator` (_AngularJS_) and the associated `$delegate` factory to perfectly meet your needs and thereby enable you to wrap all requests implicitly in proper Promises (could be observables too but they are a bad abstraction for XHR).

Comment: "I'm using Angular 1.3 so I can't use promises", I don't think this is a true statement. You can import and use q.js independently regardless what version of angular you are using.

Comment: $http returns an "Angular" promise, you can validate that here https://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/12/18/exploring-angular-1.3-es6-style-promises.html#promises-in-angular-and-q